# How to code multiple paragraphs?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, paragraphs

I want to make a website with lots and lots of paragraphs, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of achieving the spacing in the code without having to go back and place `<p>` tags for every paragraph. I have a feeling that it is not just simply HTML and CSS to achieve this. I have tried the `<pre>`element but it is spacing out each line, not the paragraph itself.

Could anyone help steer me in the right direction of how to do this?

Comment: By saying spacing in the code, you do mean the site, not the dom, right?

Comment: What styling are you trying to achieve? How is the content currently formatted? `<p>` tags should be used because first and foremost, they're semantic.

Comment: You can stylize all elements as you like. You can use `<p>` it's better by semantic, but you need to markup all your texts with start and end of each paragraph

Comment: try `<br>`. it adds a break between contents.

Comment: If it just plain content, you can use microsoft word and copy paste content to a HTML editor

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Philip, yes I mean the site, not the DOM. Ben, the paragraphs are currently in a container, in some <pre> tags, which is not giving me the result I want. I guess I'm looking for a 'shortcut' instead of having to go to every single paragraph and adding a <p> or <br> as the paragraphs are prewritten.

Answer (score 4):

`<p>` is the correct way to make a paragraph. The HTML5 specification allows you to exclude the ending `</p>` tag but many browsers and blogging engines require it so I'd advise you to include it. A `<br>` tag can be used to make a generic line break but doesn't allow you to apply CSS styles to your paragraph, so don't use it for paragraphs.

If you just don't want to type out `<p>` every time, then what you want is an IDE or a rich-text editor that can output the html for you.

Comment: Indeed. No shortcuts. You need the `<p>`s to make your document proper, but you can use all kinds of tools (smart editors, server side scripting or an actual CMS) to help you generate those tags, so you don't have to type them out in Notepad all the time.

Comment: Correct! I just wanted to add: When you are building "real" websites you'll most likely want to use some sort of content management. Wether it's a real cms or a a framework, it'll automatically fill the paragraphs from a database into a template in a loop, so you'll have to write it only once - the finished DOM will and should still have all of the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your paragraphs in [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and then convert them to HTML. In Markdown, paragraphs are delimited by two line breaks, not with tags. (Stack Overflow uses Markdown for posts.)

Example:

```
This is one paragraph in Markdown.

This is a second paragraph. As you can see, no `<p></p>` tags are necessary.
```

Comment: For more up-to-date information about Markdown, see [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/). CommonMark is a [specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/current/) for Markdown whose website includes a [cheat sheet](http://commonmark.org/help/) and an [online demo tool](http://commonmark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You want use snippets? For fast codding you can use [emmet](http://emmet.io/). For example:

You can write `p.class_name*4` and after that you will get

```
<p class="class_name"></p>
<p class="class_name"></p>
<p class="class_name"></p>
<p class="class_name"></p>
```

I hope i understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be writing a full properly `p` element and then just copy and paste it as much as you want and need.

To add space between each `p` element, use the `br` element which gives you space as it "breaks" up the rows.

Hope this helped you, happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a long text that is divided to paragraphs, and you want to display it "correctly" in the browser.
Paragraph division in texts is usually achieved by a blank line between them.

So - you should parse the existing paragraphs from the text:

```
var paragraphs  = text.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

Add HTML paragraph formatting:

```
var paragraphsInHtml = paragraphs.map(function(paragraph) {
    return "<p>" + paragraph + "</p>";
});
```

And reform the text:

```
var formattedText = paragraphsInHtml.join();
```

[code snippets are in javascript]